# How to change search result page from 3 to 1 columns in magento?

Tags: search, magento-1.7, catalog

I have to change catalog search result page layout 3 from 1 columns layout. I have tried in catalogsearch.xml, but not getting proper result. Can anyone tell me how can I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: I had tried to change layout from 3 to 1 column layout, but I am not getting search result in 1 columns layout.

Answer (score 5):

Changing the layout in catalogsearch.xml should do the trick, done this way:

Before:

```
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns.phtml</template></action>
```

After:

```
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
```

You should also clear your Magento Cache in admin>System>Cache Management.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's better to use layout.xml for that.

Answer (score 5):

Or you can in local.xml copy this:

```
 <catalogsearch_result_index>
     <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
     </reference>
 </catalogsearch_result_index>
```